# What does the "openSettings" or "openSearch" mean in Android official tutorial?

Tags: java, android

I follow the official tutorial, but the tutorial about action buttons confuses me -- [Adding Action Buttons](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#Respond).

I don't find any methods named `openSettings` or `openSearch` and the tutorial doesn't mention to define these two methods,so where are they?

Comment: They're just example method names. You'd have to implement them yourself.

Comment: The tutorial starts [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Comment: @MikeM. So how should I implement them?

Comment: @Justin I knew this, Precisely because I follow from the beginning, then these two methods comes out, I am confused

Comment: Write the two methods. E.g., `private void openSettings(){}`. Then add whatever your app needs to do in the method bodies. Like I said, they're just examples. If your app has a Settings page, you'd open it in that method. If it doesn't, you might not need that menu item.

Comment: @roger Apologies, I had mistakenly assumed you might not have realized there were previous sections of the tutorial. `openSettings` and `openSearch` could be anything. You can replace those methods with whatever you'd like. It doesn't necessarily have to relate to settings or searching.

Comment: @MikeM. I still want to know how I can implement a method to open Settings page or Search page.

Comment: @Justin  I still want to know how I can implement a method to open Settings page or Search page.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a tutorial, but that is out of scope for Stack Overflow. SO is for specific programming questions. Just do a Google search for Android tutorials. There are _tons_ of them available.